# How to search different element in array of JS?

Tags: javascript, arrays, search

I got an array.

```
var arr = [{"id": 1}, {"id": 2}, {"id": 1}];
```

I would like search different element in arr.

That is, `arr[1]`. (== `{"id":2}`)

How to search it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that has a difference:

```js
const arr = [{"id": 1}, {"id": 2}, {"id": 1}]

const result1 = arr.find(e => e.id === 2)
const result2 = arr.filter(e => e.id === 2)
const result3 = arr.map(e => e.id).filter(id => id === 2)

console.log(result1, result2, result3)
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply

```
arr.find(e => e.id == 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `filter`:

```js
var arr = [{"id": 1}, {"id": 2}, {"id": 1}];
console.log(arr.filter(obj => obj.id == 2));
```

Answer (score -1):

You can loop your array

```
for (var ele of arr) { 
   if (ele.id === 2) {
     console.log(ele);
   }
}
```

remember to use "of" instead of "in" while looping.